# Polynomial time algorithm for solving SQL queries with EXISTS and NOT EXISTS subqueries

Tags: algorithms, databases

Let $Q$ be a query in the fragment of SQL built up from basic $SELECT$ clauses using
subqueries with $EXISTS$ and $NOT EXISTS$. Then for each such fixed query $Q$ I'm trying to show that there is a polynomial-time algorithm that takes as input a finite database $D$ and determines the set of outputs of $Q$ on $D$.

I'm not sure how to do this, the evaluation involves some form of mutual recursion so perhaps it's possible to solve it accordingly but I'm not sure.

Comment: Since a SQL query with (NOT) EXISTS clauses might have, recursively, other SQL queries with more (NOT) EXISTS clauses I would suggest you to do a proof by induction (on the number of nested EXISTS subqueries).

In particular, I would prove that the complexity of evaluating such queries is O($d^k$) where $d$ is the size of the data, and $k$ only depends on the size of the query. If the query remains fixed, that means that evaluating the query over databases of increasing size increases polinomially.